# How do I track failed app downloads from iTunes store

Tags: ios, app-store

How do I track failed app downloads from iTunes store.
Is there a way to know that the user initiated the install, but failed to install the app.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is directly related to Apple's iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

No. Although I can't say this has anything to do with programming or development tools. It's better to ask this in an Apple forum.

Comment: Login to your developer account then the forum link is listed on the right. If you're not a developer then this definitely is not the place to ask the question.